# ¿Por qué una base de datos es mucho más lenta que el otra en PostgreSQL?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una Query en PostgreSQL que en local me ejecutaba perfectamente pero al ejectutarla en producción ha resultado ser horriblemente lenta.

Tanto en desarrollo como en producción ejecuté `VACUUM ANALYZE;` por si hubiese sido el problema pero todo sigue igual.

¿Qué puede estar sucendiendo y/o como se podría solucionar?

Dejo datos de estas consultas si alguien ve en ellas la causa:

**Query:**

```
explain analyze SELECT "usuario"."id", [...] 
FROM "usuario" INNER JOIN "pago" ON ( "usuario"."id" = "pago"."customer_id" )
WHERE ("usuario"."estado" = 0 AND "pago"."id" IS NOT NULL AND NOT ("usuario"."id" IN (SELECT U1."usuario_id" AS Col1 FROM "compra" U1 WHERE U1."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND NOT ("usuario"."id" IN (SELECT U1."user_id" AS Col1 FROM "llamada" U1 WHERE U1."result_call" >= 20)))
```

**Producción:**

PostgreSQL 9.3.10

https://explain.depesz.com/s/vH3

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=40816.55..17773313.78 rows=4686 width=425) (actual time=111460.456..1015832.289 rows=1 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: ("usuario".id = pago.customer_id)
   ->  Index Scan using "usuario_pkey" on "usuario"  (cost=21.35..17998731.10 rows=2206 width=425) (actual time=1635.214..1015665.631 rows=57 loops=1)
         Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (estado = 0) AND (NOT (SubPlan 1)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 12394
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Seq Scan on "llamada" u1_1  (cost=0.00..20.38 rows=277 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Filter: (result_call >= 20)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2769.55 rows=50037 width=4) (actual time=0.012..58.055 rows=23514 loops=8835)
                 ->  Seq Scan on pago u1  (cost=0.00..2323.37 rows=50037 width=4) (actual time=0.014..165.809 rows=50057 loops=1)
                       Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
   ->  Index Scan using pago_customer_id on pago  (cost=0.29..2915.78 rows=26413 width=4) (actual time=0.014..98.417 rows=26543 loops=1)
         Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
 Total runtime: 1015836.596 ms
(15 rows)
```

**Entorno de desarrollo:**

PostgreSQL 9.5.1

https://explain.depesz.com/s/J6uY

```
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3312.44..4085.27 rows=3727 width=427) (actual time=35.212..38.552 rows=1 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (pago.customer_id = "usuario".id)
   ->  Seq Scan on pago  (cost=0.00..658.23 rows=20623 width=4) (actual time=0.019..2.477 rows=20623 loops=1)
         Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
   ->  Hash  (cost=3290.46..3290.46 rows=1758 width=427) (actual time=34.655..34.655 rows=43 loops=1)
         Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 28kB
         ->  Seq Scan on "usuario"  (cost=2003.21..3290.46 rows=1758 width=427) (actual time=30.532..34.623 rows=43 loops=1)
               Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (estado = 0))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 9686
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Seq Scan on pago u1  (cost=0.00..1893.71 rows=43371 width=4) (actual time=0.020..15.883 rows=43371 loops=1)
                       Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
               SubPlan 2
                 ->  Seq Scan on "llamada" u1_1  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                       Filter: (result_call >= 20)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 5
 Planning time: 5.674 ms
 Execution time: 47.179 ms
```

Comment: Tal vez ayudaría al análisis saber si: 1) índices que tienen las tablas involucradas (y si hay difencia en cada ambiente); 2) Cantidad de registros (si bien pueden deducirse del plan) como para que no queden dudas.

Comment: Por otro lado, yo personalmente cambiaría los `NOT(usuario IN (SELECT u FROM  TABLE_X) )` por `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si a alguien más tiene este problema y puede serle útil:

Modifiqué mi configuración de postgresql en `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`

```
work_mem = 2MB (por defecto es #work_mem = 1MB)
```

Y en una terminal de psql reinicié la configuración (sin parada de servicio):

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Para solucionar el problema tuve que seguir la pista a `Materialize` del query plan. Por lo que he podido entender, Materialize recupera de disco (en vez de memoria). Esto se da cuando la query es más grande que lo que puede almacenar `work_men`. De todas formas, si alguien pudiese explicar cómo trabaja exáctamente `Materialize` lo agradecería ya que no he encontrado mucha información al respecto :)

Comment: ¡Dale "aceptar" a tu respuesta!  ¡Buen trabajo de detective!  Lo que hace el nodo Materialize es escribir a disco el resultado de su nodo hijo, de manera que cuando el padre necesite volver a leerlo se pueda mirar lo que se escribió en lugar de ejecutar esa parte de la consulta otra vez.El `work_mem` mayor permite que ese resultado quepa en una tabla hash lo cual permite usar el hash join. Quizás los NOT (SELECT .. IN ..) se puedan escribir mejor como `... NOT IN ...` o NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, aun no puedo crear comentarios, así que lo agrego como respuesta... es que creo que falta información...

¿Las versiones de Psql de desarrollo y producción son las mismas?
¿Las tablas tienen indices?

Hay mucha tiempo de diferencia entre produccion y desarrollo, intenta nuevamente en desarrollo, pero ejecuta antes esto:

SET enable_seqscan TO 'off';

y comenta el tiempo acá